# UITableView Crashing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView I add as a subview of `self.view` and it crashes at 

`- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Here is my code:

interface (in CRFeedViewController.m)
    `@property (assign) BOOL dataIsLoaded;`

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(dataIsLoaded == YES)
    {
        return [self.items count];
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

// Return a cell for the index path
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Cell label
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Tweet";

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)getTimeLine {
    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted == YES)
         {
             NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

             if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
             {
                 ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];

                 NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json"];

                 NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                 [parameters setObject:@"20" forKey:@"count"];
                 [parameters setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];

                 SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestURL parameters:parameters];

                 postRequest.account = twitterAccount;

                 [postRequest performRequestWithHandler: ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                  {
                      self.items = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                      if (self.items.count != 0) {
                          dataIsLoaded = YES;
                          [self.tableView reloadData];
                      }
                      else {
                          NSLog(@"No items");
                      }
                  }];
             }
         } else {
             NSLog(@"No access");
         }
     }];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self getTimeLine];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /**
     *  TABLE VIEW
     *  Add subview of the table
     */
    self.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", nil];

    CGRect tableViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableViewRect style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

## EDIT

Here is my complete code, I'm sorry I don't understand all of this yet, I am still very new.

.h

```
//
//  CRFeedViewController.h
//  Twitter
//
//  Created by Cody Robertson on 6/27/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Cody Robertson. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>

@interface CRFeedViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *items;

@end
```

.m

```
//
//  CRFeedViewController.m
//  Twitter
//
//  Created by Cody Robertson on 6/27/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Cody Robertson. All rights reserved.
//

#import "CRFeedViewController.h"

#import "CRComposeViewController.h"
#import "CRSearchViewController.h"

@interface CRFeedViewController ()

@property (assign) BOOL dataIsLoaded;

- (void) composeTweet: (id) sender;
- (void) searchTweets: (id) sender;

- (void) getTimeLine;

@end

@implementation CRFeedViewController

@synthesize dataIsLoaded;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        /**
         *  NAV BAR
         *  Add icon and button to nav bar
         */

        // Add Twitter Icon as Title
        UIImageView *UINavTitleLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavBarLogo.png"]];
        UINavTitleLogo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        self.navigationItem.titleView = UINavTitleLogo;

        // Add Search & Compose Icon
        UIImage *UISearchNavButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Search.png"];
        UIBarButtonItem *CRSearchNavButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:UISearchNavButton style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(searchTweets:)];

        UIImage *UIComposeNavButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Compose.png"];
        UIBarButtonItem *CRComposeNavButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:UIComposeNavButton style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(composeTweet:)];

        NSArray *UINavItems = @[CRComposeNavButton, CRSearchNavButton];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = UINavItems;

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
            UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]
        }];

        /**
         *  TAB BAR
         *  Add icon and label to task bar
         */
        UIImage *CRFeedTabBarIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"];
        UITabBarItem *CRFeedTabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" image:CRFeedTabBarIcon tag:0];
        self.tabBarItem = CRFeedTabBarItem;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) composeTweet:(id)sender
{
    /**
     *      PUSH VIEW TO COMPOSE
     *      Load the compose view
     */
    CRComposeViewController *CRCompose = [[CRComposeViewController alloc] init];
    CRCompose.title = @"New Tweet";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:CRCompose animated:YES];
}

- (void) searchTweets:(id)sender
{
    /**
     *      PUSH VIEW TO SEARCH
     *      Load the search view
     */
    CRSearchViewController *CRSearch = [[CRSearchViewController alloc] init];
    CRSearch.title = @"Search";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:CRSearch animated:YES];
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(dataIsLoaded == YES)
    {
        return [self.items count];
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

// Return a cell for the index path
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Cell label
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Tweet";

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)getTimeLine {
    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted == YES)
         {
             NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

             if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
             {
                 ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];

                 NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json"];

                 NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                 [parameters setObject:@"20" forKey:@"count"];
                 [parameters setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];

                 SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:requestURL parameters:parameters];

                 postRequest.account = twitterAccount;

                 [postRequest performRequestWithHandler: ^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                  {
                      self.items = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                      if (self.items.count != 0) {
                          dataIsLoaded = YES;
                          [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                      }
                      else {
                          NSLog(@"No items");
                      }
                  }];
             }
         } else {
             NSLog(@"No access");
         }
     }];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self getTimeLine];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /**
     *  TABLE VIEW
     *  Add subview of the table
     */
    self.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", nil];

    CGRect tableViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableViewRect style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Define items, please.

Comment: @TBlue Please explain..

Comment: If you can't define items, then why do you use it in the first place?

Comment: Whenever you post a question about an error you must include the complete error in your question. Also indicated which exact line of code is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Add the delegate first so those methods are ran. Don't forget to subscribe to the delegate in your .h as well.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;
```

// In your viewDidLoad

```
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I have them subscribed it in my .h, and added this and it is still crashing at that method.

Comment: Place a breakpoint in your numberOfRowsInSection and see where it's crashing. Also, post your @property for that array here.

Comment: The breakpoint is at whatever is inside of that method. At one point it crashed at `return [self.items count]` now it is crashing at `if(dataIsLoaded == YES) {`

Comment: Create that BOOL as @property (nonatomic) BOOL dataIsLoaded; and comment out your viewWillAppear method to make sure that isn't firing.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `reloadData` method on the main thread:

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Not sure if this is causing your crash, but you need to init your cells with the reuse identifier:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;
```

I would recommend that you post the trace logged in Xcode when the app crashes. It will give a better understanding as to why your app is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You return 1 cell even if you don't have data. You should return 0

Comment: It perfectly fine to return 1 if there is no data. You may wish to show a "Loading..." row for example. As long as the other table view data source and delegate methods handle the case properly, this is fine.

Comment: Its ok sure. But it sounds like this person is just getting acquainted with the tableview and there isn't an out of bounds array check in the cell for row... So a simple failsafe is the 0

Comment: Except the current `cellForRow...` method just creates an empty cell so there is no danger. And the error is claimed to be in the `numberOfRowsInSection...` method anyway. Until we are told the actual error, this question can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is happening in the `numberOfRows` method, then the culprit is most likely:

```
[self.items count];
```

The most likely case this causes an error is if `self.items` does not have a `count` method. In your `viewDidLoad`, you set it to an `NSArray`, which does have a `count` method. However, there is one other place you set `self.items`:

```
self.items = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```

The result of that method most likely does not have a `count` method, and therefore is not an `NSArray`, yet you are storing it in a variable that is defined as `NSArray`.

After that line, above, put the following code:

```
NSLog(@"Class: %@", NSStringFromClass([self.items class]));
```

If the output is not `NSArray`, you most likely have a programming error.

---

Also, it looks like you are using multiple threads, to read/write to the same variable. This is usually not a good idea without implementing some sort of thread safety on those properties.